# how to create a A record in VPS hosting using putty for vps.abc.com

Tags: vps

I bought a vps hosting for one month to do a test drive. When i registered they also registered vps.mysite.com which is now pointing to a different ip(i cheched by pinging).

This vps is just plain without any extra bundles so no control panel(cPanel).

How to create A record using Putty. Is it possible? I dont have any idea of my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an A record using putty unfortunately.

You would need to change the A record for vps.mydomain.com in your domain if you have any way of managing it, if the management of the dns depends on your VPS hosting (or another provider) you should email them to change the record.

Meanwhile you can just configure the new IP address in putty directly in order to connect through ssh, you don't need a dns name for doing so.

Good luck!

Comment: oh... i see... ok.